Did a fresh install on old macbook pro, battery became nonfunctional (turns off when disconnected from power)
I have a mid 2014 macbook pro retina that I installed windows 10 on. I had to wipe the drive completely to do so. I installed the drivers using brigadier. The machine shuts off the moment I disconnect the power cable, but it reports 100% full battery. The battery is an ifixit one that I'd swapped out earlier, but there's no reason for me to think it's dead (it was functional before). I did the battery check on windows using powercfg /batteryreport command, and it reports 78,000 mAh available out of the 86-something design capacity.
When I plug in the charger, the light is immediately green, indicating full battery. When I was on mac, prior to the disk wipe, it did show orange as well, although I do not recall if I disconnected it recently.
I did an SMC reset, but it did not do anything. Is it possible that I wiped info related to SMC or NVRAM by mistake, when wiping the disk? How can I fix this issue, or determine if the battery is truly dead?
update: opened it up, disconnected and reconnected the battery. I see no issues relating to corrosion or dirt in the connections. I'd thoroughly cleaned this device back when I replaced the battery ~2 years ago anyway.

Green means there's power, but no charging is happening. It doesn't mean "battery is full", as such. Do you have macOS on an external drive you can boot from and have a look at the Battery data in System Information?

@benwiggy I just restored macos big sur from recovery. It says 10 cycles, and service required. Coconut battery says 90% of original capacity but status poor. Reset SMC and NVRAM again, but it's still happening. I guess ifixit batteries are just trash.

Generally speaking iFixit gets their batteries from the same places everyone else does. However it could be that there is something wrong with battery management in the Mac that resetting the SMC will not effect. And if Coconut battery says "status poor" and macOS says "service required" the battery may be defective. How old is the battery? Can you return it under warranty?
